# HP Pavilion dv6 Notepad - touchpad buttons - disable clicking sound

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to stop the annoying clicking sound made when tapping the touchpad buttons on my HP Pavilion dv6 Notepad.  There doesn't seem to be an option to do so in the Synaptics touchpad settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel; open Sound; select the Sounds tab; in the list below search for appropriately named property; if there is one, select it, open the drop-down list below, scroll it up and select None.